# SQL Query - Understanding the Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display greatest selling product by quantity

```
Product Table
ProductID  ProductName
1          AA   
2          BB
3          CC
[Order Details] Table
OrderID ProductID  Quantity DateOfOrder
1       1            10    SomeDate   
2       1            100     ,,
3       2            15      ,, 
4       1            15      ,,   
5       2            20      ,, 
6       2            30      ,, 
7       1            100     ,,

Expected Output

Product By Quantity  AA
```

Because sum(quantity)=  225

I used:

```
select 'Product By Quantity' + ProductName 
from
Products 
where ProductID in
 (select 
       ProductID
  from 
       [Order Details] det 
  where Quantity=
                (
                  select max(SUM(Quantity)) 
                  from [Order Details] od
                  where
                  od.ProductID=det.ProductID
                )
  )
```

I got error : `"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"`

Please explain me why the syntax fails here so that in future i will write appropriate query by 
knowing the correct syntax.Also give me the correct query.

Thank you everybody in advance.

### Edit

I was trying for the following query

```
SELECT 'Best Selling Product'+ProductName
FROM 
Products
WHERE ProductID =
 (
       SELECT ProductID
       FROM [Order Details]
       GROUP BY ProductID
       HAVING SUM(Quantity) = (
                               SELECT MAX(SQ)
                               FROM (
                                       SELECT SUM(Quantity) as SQ
                                       FROM [Order Details]
                                       GROUP BY ProductID
                                    ) AS OD))
```

Comment: The error message says it already. You use an aggregate function inside an other aggregate function.

Comment: Can you show us the data you are dealing with and some desired output.  I think your problem lies in what you are trying to do, not the max(sum()) issue.

Comment: the error is indeed putting `sum()` inside `max()`, and your answer to Martijn does not make sense. Try giving an example and we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 'Product By Quantity' + ProductName  from Products p
join 
(
select top 1 sum(Quantity) sq, od.ProductId 
from [Order Details] od
group by od.ProductId 
order by 1 desc
) bsp on p.productid = bsp.ProductId
```

`bsp` stands for Best Selling Product

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you're trying to get to:

```
select top 1 p.product_name, sum(od.quantity) as total_quantity
    from products p
        inner join [order details] od
            on p.productid = od.productid
    group by p.productid, p.product_name
    order by total_quantity desc
```

Comment: Group by `product_name` is incorrect. Say, I have a `super blaster (id=4)` and a `super blaster (id=6)` but it so happens that the latter isn't selling at all.

Comment: @Denis: Thx. I added productid to the group by clause to cover this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

looks like select max(SUM(Quantity)) is wrong. The maximum of the sum doesn't have any meaning. Did you mean max(Quantity)?

Comment: Maximum value of Sum(Quantity) of any product

Comment: @Amit - in SQL sum is the total of all the values returned for a column within the query...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT      TOP 1
            SUM(o.Quantity)
            ,p.ProductName
FROM        [Order Details] AS o
INNER JOIN  [Products] AS p ON p.ProductID = o.ProductID
GROUP BY    p.ProductID
            ,p.ProductName
ORDER BY    SUM(o.Quantity) DESC
```

Comment: Close, but not quite right. You're ordering by the individual quantities rather than the sum. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754691/sql-query-understanding-the-syntax/3754754#3754754).